# Carousel Caption Towards The Right

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

I have some html codes whereby when I ran it, it was displayed really nice. However, when I copied the same code to asp.net, it became smaller the overall font of the website and the carousel slider turned out ugly. The pictures in the slider became quite distorted and the caption was headed towards the right more. The 3 slider indicator at the bottom of the carousel always turned round when I click on it. 
https://pasteboard.co/IFrM6Zo.png

This is the version that I got with my html and it looks way better but my target here is the asp.net which is the up one. 
https://pasteboard.co/IFrLK8O.png

My aim is to centralize the caption in the centre and also have 3 nice little carousel indicators at the bottom. any ideas why the image in the asp,net is like distorted? It does not show the full image but rather a very enlarged version. I removed the carousel indicators from my asp.net but i want to achieve it the way i did with my html.

This is my code for the carousel.

```
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="7000">


    <div class="carousel-inner" role="Listbox">
        <!--First slide -->
        <div class="carousel-item active" style="background-image: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/2237797/pexels-photo-2237797.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=computer-device-electronics-2237797.jpg&fm=jpg);">
            <div class="carousel-caption text-center">
                <h1>Welcome to Nuno</h1>
                <h3>Animated Bootstrap Theme</h3>
                <a class="btn btn-outline-light btn-lg" href="#about">Get Started</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--Second slide-->
        <div class="carousel-item" style="background-image: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/2237797/pexels-photo-2237797.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=computer-device-electronics-2237797.jpg&fm=jpg);"></div>
        <!--Third slide-->
        <div class="carousel-item" style="background-image: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/669228/pexels-photo-669228.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=calendar-cellphone-computer-keyboard-669228.jpg&fm=jpg);"></div>
    </div>

    <!--Previous and next buttons -->
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </a>

    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </a>
</div>
```

This is the css

```
.carousel-item {
height: 100vh;
position: center;
 }

.carousel-item {
transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease;
transition: transform 0.5s ease;
transition: transform 0.5s ease, -webkit-transform 0.5s ease;
-webkit-backface-visibility: visible;
backface-visibility: visible;
 }

.carousel-caption {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
text-transform: uppercase;
width: 100%;
right: 0;
left: 0;
transform: translateY(-50%);
 }

.carousel-caption h1 {
    font-size: 3.8rem;
    font-weight: 700;
    letter-spacing: .3rem;
    text-shadow: .1rem .1rem .8rem black;
    padding-bottom: 1rem;
 }

.carousel-caption h3 {
    font-size: 2rem;
    text-shadow: .1rem .1rem .5rem black;
    padding-bottom: 1.6rem;
 }

.btn-lg {
border-width: medium;
border-radius: 0;
font-size: 14px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

ok so i think i fixed it for you !
please check my fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/r6450mup/

i think you were missing:

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
```

hope i helped !